# Find the address and value of SQSUM in memory before and after the program is executed. (KEIL Uvision5)

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

This is on a Homework assignment for my intro to computer architecture and organization class.

Here is the full question:

Write code to calculate the sum of the square of numbers between 1 and 5.
Create a variable SQSUM, initialize it with 0, and store the sum of the square of numbers between 1 and 5 in `SQSUM`.
Find the address and Value of `SQSUM` in memory before and after the program is executed.

We are using `Keil Uvision 5 MDK-ARM` Version `5.28` with legacy support for `ARM7, ARM9` and `cortex-R`

I have the code

```
    AREA Long, CODE, READWRITE 
    ENTRY
    MOV r0, #0 
    MOV r1, #1
```

Loop    MUL r2,r1,r1
        ADD r0,r0,r2

```
    ADD r1,r1,#1
    CMP r1, #6
    BNE Loop
    STR r0, SQSUM
```

S       B S
SQSUM   DCD 0
        END

which works, it is the last part I can not figure out, i know the values i just do not have a clue how to find the address.

Please help 
Thank you